# Random Sleep in Crontab/Terminal

Tags: linux, cron, command-line-interface, ubuntu-16.04, terminal

I want in terminal or in crontab(both) be able to put a random time.

Something like

```
Sleep $(1-300)  pkill screen && ./start
```

just a random simple example

Comment: in bash shell, this will give you a random number good enough for your question as asked: `$(( RANDOM % 300 ))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sleep for 1 to 300 seconds using the following command :

`sleep $(( ( RANDOM % 300 )  + 1 ))`

So, to run a command just after that, use `sleep $(( ( RANDOM % 300 )  + 1 )) && your command`

This answer assume you are using bash

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault.  While this is technically correct, answering duplicate questions is discouraged.

Comment: Oh -- Sorry! Should I delete the answer ?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352194/what-to-do-with-answer-on-duplicate-question